# LinearLayout@422725b0 is not a sliding drawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

Hi I have been going crazy with this.

There are several questions out there but none have seems to fix my problem.
I am getting an error when ever I try to style a drawer layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="start"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="test"
        android:background="@drawable/black"
        android:textColor="#94A1A1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"  
        android:layout_weight="1"      
    />  

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#323232"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the Java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.drawertest;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This example illustrates a common usage of the DrawerLayout widget
 * in the Android support library.
 * <p/>
 * <p>When a navigation (left) drawer is present, the host activity should detect presses of
 * the action bar's Up affordance as a signal to open and close the navigation drawer. The
 * ActionBarDrawerToggle facilitates this behavior.
 * Items within the drawer should fall into one of two categories:</p>
 * <p/>
 * <ul>
 * <li><strong>View switches</strong>. A view switch follows the same basic policies as
 * list or tab navigation in that a view switch does not create navigation history.
 * This pattern should only be used at the root activity of a task, leaving some form
 * of Up navigation active for activities further down the navigation hierarchy.</li>
 * <li><strong>Selective Up</strong>. The drawer allows the user to choose an alternate
 * parent for Up navigation. This allows a user to jump across an app's navigation
 * hierarchy at will. The application should treat this as it treats Up navigation from
 * a different task, replacing the current task stack using TaskStackBuilder or similar.
 * This is the only form of navigation drawer that should be used outside of the root
 * activity of a task.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * <p>Right side drawers should be used for actions, not navigation. This follows the pattern
 * established by the Action Bar that navigation should be to the left and actions to the right.
 * An action should be an operation performed on the current contents of the window,
 * for example enabling or disabling a data overlay on top of the current content.</p>
 */


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    public TextView title;
    public int theme = 1;
    public int theme2 = 1;
    public Drawable background = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(theme == 1){
       setTheme(R.style.CustomActionBarTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.CustomActionBarBlueTheme);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_child);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
               // getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(linearLayout);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            updatebackground(view,position);
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
    private void updatebackground(View view,int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        int right = view.getPaddingRight();
        int left = view.getPaddingLeft();
        int top = view.getPaddingTop();
        int bottom = view.getPaddingBottom();
        switch(position) {
        case 0 : 
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redbackground);
                 background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red);

        break;
        case 1 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebackground);
                 background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue);

        break;
        case 2 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.brownbackground);
                 background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brown);

        break;
        case 3 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenbackground);
        background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green);

        break;
        case 4 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orangebackground);
        background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange);

        break;
        case 5 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purplebackground);
        background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.purple);

        break;
        case 6 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pinkbackground);
        background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pink);

        break;
        case 7 : view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowbackground);
        background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow);

        break;
        default: view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackbackground);
        background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black);


        }
        view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        if(theme == 1){
            theme =2;
        }else {
            theme =1;
        }

    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
11-27 00:56:56.545: E/AndroidRuntime(10000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drawertest/com.example.drawertest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout@422725b0 is not a sliding drawer
```

Any help would be great thanks in advance

Comment: Why that LinearLayout in your activity

Comment: I'm guessing you have tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: If you can't figure it out, you could remove the LinearLayout as Ansar suggests.  You can replace `isDrawerOpen(linearLayout)` with `isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The view must have either Gravity.LEFT or Gravity.RIGHT to be recognized as a sliding drawer. You can replace

```
android:gravity="start"
```

with

```
android:gravity="left"
```

or, as suggested above alternatively replace

```
isDrawerOpen(linearLayout)
```

with

```
isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)
```

Comment: in my case it was android:layout_gravity="left"

Comment: android:layout_gravity="start" is more correct answer

Answer (score 7):

I just added

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also had such an issue. After I added

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

everything worked out fine.

Comment: android:layout_gravity="start" is more correct answer