# DrawerLayout with Gridviewand LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to make use a DrawerLayout but without ListView and I get an error. I want to have 5 icons with text in the drawer. I am using a LinearLayout and gridview to get that.

Here is the error

```
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{42059670 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f050044 app:id/drawer_linearlayout} is not a sliding drawer
```

MenuActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteatarskopje.R;
import com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteater.adapter.DrawerAdapter;
import com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteater.adapter.GridGalleryAdapter;
import com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteater.datamodel.DrawerItem;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private LinearLayout mDrawerLinear;
    private GridView mDrawerGrid;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLinear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_linearlayout);
        mDrawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_grid);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(null);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE); 

        mDrawerGrid.setAdapter(new DrawerAdapter(this, getDrawerItems()));
        mDrawerGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());


        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.action_bar_menu_icon, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) 
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0);
        }

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements GridView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ProgramFragment(this);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ListArtistFragment(this);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ContactFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerGrid.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerGrid.setSelection(position);
            setTitle("lala");
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mDrawerTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private List<DrawerItem> getDrawerItems() {
        List<DrawerItem> items = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        DrawerItem item = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.nav_drawer_programa_icon,
                R.string.drawer_program);
        items.add(item);
        item = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.nav_drawer_artisti_icon,
                R.string.drawer_artists);
        items.add(item);
        item = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.nav_drawer_galerija_icon,
                R.string.drawer_gallery);
        items.add(item);
        item = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.nav_drawer_istorijat_icon,
                R.string.drawer_about);
        items.add(item);
        item = new DrawerItem(R.drawable.nav_drawer_kontakt_icon,
                R.string.drawer_contact);
        items.add(item);
        return items;
    }
}
```

This is the xml. activity_menu.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_scroll" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Log:

```
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875): Process: com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteatarskopje, PID: 17875
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteatarskopje/com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteater.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{42059670 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f050044 app:id/drawer_linearlayout} is not a sliding drawer
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{42059670 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f050044 app:id/drawer_linearlayout} is not a sliding drawer
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1170)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteater.MenuActivity.displayView(MenuActivity.java:149)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at com.codewell.unltd.mk.dramskiteater.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:83)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-08 10:56:39.358: E/AndroidRuntime(17875):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Add the appropriate `layout_gravity` attribute to your LinearLayout.

Comment: View [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235988/linearlayout422725b0-is-not-a-sliding-drawer) for more info on Mike's answer

Comment: @MikeM.  I added this to the Linear layout android:layout_gravity="start". Still crashes

Comment: I tried it with layout_gravity="left" too still crashes

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: OK thanks guys! It worked with layout_gravity=left. I just had another stupid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thx to Mike M. and Toon Borgers I fixed the error.  In the xml I had to put layout_gravity="left" atribute in the Linear layout